# adding multiple sublayers in Xcode 4? only one displays

Tags: objective-c, xcode, calayer

I am trying to add two CALayers as sublayers from an array to the layer of my view.  The following code only adds the last sublayer attempted (it is named q).  I'm trying to get this to work with just two in an array first so that I can later add as many as I'd like with a for loop.  Any suggestions on getting two sublayers to display simultaneously?

ViewController.h is

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    UIImage *beeImage;

    UIImageView *beeView;
    CALayer *beeLayer;
    CABasicAnimation *animation;

    NSMutableArray *beeArray;

    }

@property(retain,nonatomic) UIImage *beeImage;
@property(retain,nonatomic) NSArray *beeArray;
@property(retain,nonatomic) UIImageView *beeView;
@property(retain,nonatomic) CALayer *beeLayer;
@property(retain,nonatomic)CABasicAnimation *animation;
-(void) animate;
-(void) makeSwarm;

@end
```

this is ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self makeSwarm];
}

-(void) makeSwarm{

    self.view.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
    self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0;
    self.view.layer.frame = CGRectInset(self.view.layer.frame, 20, 20);

    CGRect beeFrame;
    beeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    beeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bee50x55px.png"];
    beeFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, beeImage.size.width, beeImage.size.height);
    beeView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:beeFrame];
    beeView.image = beeImage;    
    beeLayer = [beeView layer];


    CALayer *p = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    CALayer *q = [[CALayer alloc] init];


    [beeArray addObject: beeLayer];     
    [beeArray addObject: beeLayer];  

    p = [beeArray objectAtIndex: 0];    

    [p setPosition:CGPointMake(10, 10)];
    p.zPosition=0;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:p];

    q = [beeArray objectAtIndex: 1];    

    [q setPosition:CGPointMake(160,240)];
    q.zPosition=1;
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:q below:p];        


}
```

Comment: It might be because it is the same object.  Try `[beeArray addObject:[beeLayer copy]];` instead.

Comment: Yes it would be because they are the same object, and I am pretty sure CALayers do not support copying, so create an entirely new instance of a CALayer would be the best option

Comment: Thank you!  Going my first group animation so this is a necessary prereq for me. Am I correct that the problem was insufficient understanding of pointers (it is a new concept for me)?

Answer (score 0):

I do not yet know how (or if it is possible) to accept an answer left in the comments.  So, in order to mark this as answered, I will quote the first correct answer.  I'm sorry if this doesn't correctly help lnafziger in rep here, but I do not know what else to do.

lnafziger said...

"It might be because it is the same object. Try [beeArray addObject:[beeLayer copy]]; instead. – lnafziger"

This worked.  Thank you very much.